# Kotlin speechregognizer does no longer end

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, speech-recognition, duration

I try to get a speechrecognizer running in Kotlin with Android Studio.
Having resolved my compiler problems with help from stackoverflow I now face the following problem: The speechRecognizer does no longer end.

I am sure, yesterday after waiting a default time of may be 3 to 5 seconds the speechcontrol ended. When I spoke nothing, the anwer was "try it again" , elsewhere it ended correctly.

Now the "input-Speech-window does not end until i click into the window.
AND I HAVE NO IDEA; WHAT I COULD HAVE CHANGED !!!!

I add the "RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 100" (what is NOT SUGGESTED !!), but also doesn't help

This is the code for the speechrecognizer

```
fun btnhear(view: View) {
    val  speechRecognitionIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    speechRecognitionIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().toString())
    speechRecognitionIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 100)
    startActivityForResult(speechRecognitionIntent, SPEECHINTENTRQ)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    textView.text = "vor der if loop " + requestCode + " " + resultCode
    //var speechresult: String? = String()
    if (requestCode == SPEECHINTENTRQ  &&  resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        textView.text = "in der if loop " + Activity.RESULT_OK
        var speechresult2: ArrayList<String> =
            data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS) ?: ArrayList()
        if (speechresult2.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            textView.text = "nothing heard " + Activity.RESULT_OK
        }
        else {
            var spokenText = speechresult2[0]
            editText.setText(spokenText)
        }
    }
    else
    editText.setText("Keine Eingabe"+requestCode)

    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

I appreciate any idea, what i could have made wrong.
I run it on emulator und tried 2, Pixel 2 API28 and Pixel  API 28

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: my answer is:
I don't know why, but by accident I lost my speech recognition on the Emulator.
I try running / debugging on the smartphone via USB device connection.

Trying for hours to get the speech recognition running again on the emulator, but doesn't work again. Checking lots of internet-tips, trying (i think ALL ) settings, installing google assistant, running with or without login to my account, nothing helped.
It' s a pity, but i think i have to skip it and test directly on the smartphone (I have 3 smartphones with working "Ok google ", but on emulator i fail ....

Answer (score 0):

and testing on smartphone - the app works as expected